# Giving 'hints' problem

Tags: python, tuples

I have a simple word jumble game. I made the jumble already, but now I want to add a 'hint' system. I don't know how to have 1 item from tuples show up. I have 2 tuples, and I want to pull from the 2nd tuple based on the what the first tuple is. I have a `WORD=("x", "y", "z")` and `HINT=("x", "y", "z")`. When the user enters `"hint"`, I want the program to return the corresponding value from `HINT`. I tried:

```
for h in HINT:
    if guess=="hint":
        print h
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, and just prints all of the HINT values.

If I had:

```
hints=dict(zip(WORDS, HINT))
if guess=="hint":
    print "Here's a hint:", hints[correct]
while (guess !=correct) and (guess != ""):
    print "Sorry, that's not the answer."
    guess=raw_input("Your guess: ")
    guess=guess.lower()
    if guess==correct:
        print "That's it! You guessed it!\n"
print "Thanks for playing."
```

would there be any way for me to make it NOT print "Sorry, that's not it."? (also, 'correct' here is the word)

Comment: it's not clear how you select to what to pull from the `HINT`. what the value should correspond to?

Comment: In general, you can access the n-th access of the list/tuple like this: `myList[n]`.

Gruszczy's idea seems better suited to solve this particular problem, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dictionary:

```
  hints = dict(zip(WORD, HINT))
```

and then:

```
  if guess=='hint':
    print hints[current_word]
```

Simple `if` is not enough?

```
if guess != 'hint':
  print "Sorry, that's not the answer."
```

Comment: If I had:
{
hints=dict(zip(WORDS, HINT))
if guess=="hint":
    print "Here's a hint:", hints[correct]
while (guess !=correct) and (guess != ""):
    print "Sorry, that's not it."
    guess=raw_input("Your guess: ")
    guess=guess.lower()
    if guess==correct:
        print "That's it! You guessed it!\n"
print "Thanks for playing."
}
would there be any way for me to make it NOT print "Sorry, that's not it."? (also, 'correct' here is the word)

Comment: Please, add this code to the question as an edit with code formatting, because right now it is impossible to say, what there is ;-)